# Does Flutter animations slowdown the flutter app? performance wise

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-widget

I am building a flutter app where i use some flutter-animations tag like hero tag which is useful to take a picture from one screen to another using smooth animation. Now i wonder, when we see animations which are not like an image to shows in just one go but it shows in frame by frame and for every frame flutter change it's state then it must be slow down the performance of app in my opinon. What you say sir?

Comment: Try with separating the context(create new widget) for animation item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. But by that same logic, showing anything on the screen also slows the app down. Why even have an image at all? Why not just display an empty screen?

So clearly, the real question is: is the tradeoff worth it, does it make your app drop below 60 fps or whatever you are targeting? Does adding an animation make your app easier to use and more polished? In almost all cases, the answer is yes, adding animations is well worth it.